# Java JUnit The import org cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I am on arch linux and using eclipse `2018-09 (4.9.0)` with `openjdk10-src`. But my JUnit import is not working.

It says on adding the classpath:

> Source location: Not found

[image]

And after adding JUnit in classpath its still not working:

> The import org cannot be resolved

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a `module-info.java`.

You have three options:

1. If you don't need the module system's features, simply remove the `module-info.java`
2. Make sure that the junit jars are on the modulepath and you have matching `requires` statements in your `module-info.java`
3. As having test dependencies in the module-info.java is a bad idea, you can leave the junit jars on the classpath, but create a separate test source folder (e.g. `src-tests` and make sure to configure the setting `Contains test sources`; see https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.8/jdt.php#JavaViewsAndDialogs; it will need  with a separate output folder, e.g. `bin-tests`) and move your tests there.
   (Wenn compiling test sources in a named module, eclipse implicitely adds --add-reads=ALL-UNNAMED, as maven does)

(Also just to be sure check that you are using the package names from junit 5 and not from junit 4.)